# How to copy all files from s3 folder to another folder in the same bucket and if subfolder does not exist create during copy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy all files from one s3 subfolder to another subfolder within same bucket, and if destination subfolder does not exist so it should be created before copy operation. I want to do this with the help of boto3 . What could be steps to do this ?
**requirement:**

bucketname/subfolder/files
bucketname/copysubfolder/

if copysubfolder does not exist at the time of copying all files from subfolder , first copysubfolder should be created otherwise if copysubfolder  exists it should directly copy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete above requirement , below is code . I have done using boto3 .

```
import boto3
old_bucket_name = bucket_name
old_prefix = 'subfolder/full_load/'
new_bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
new_prefix = 'subfolder/tmp/'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
old_bucket = s3.Bucket(old_bucket_name)
new_bucket = s3.Bucket(new_bucket_name)

for obj in old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix):
    old_source = { 'Bucket': old_bucket_name,
                   'Key': obj.key}
    # replace the prefix
    new_key = obj.key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix, 1)
    new_obj = new_bucket.Object(new_key)
    new_obj.copy(old_source)
```

Comment: Nice! You can also use `bucket.copy(copy_source, 'otherkey')` without creating the target object. See: [`Bucket.copy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.copy)